# Massive slow down when changing networks

Tags: performance, samsung-galaxy-note-4

Whenever my phone switches from cellular to wifi or the reverse, the phone effectively stalls.  This can last for a minute or so.  It is still functional during this time, but very slow and stuttering (if in the middle of an animation it will do a few frames, then stop for several seconds, then do a few more).

I am thinking that one or more apps are set to wake up when the network status changes, and either they are conflicting with each other or holding the cpu while they wait for the network to be finally ready.

What should I use to work this out?  I have betterbatterystats installed, amplify, and greenify.  I have taken a few stabs at working out what might be causing this (mostly by greenifying any app that is destined to wake when the network changes), and some random click-and-hope type attempts to figure it out.

The phone is a Samsung Note 4, N910G running kitkat.

Comment: I'm not sure how to approach the issue, but I would attempt [tag:logging]. Start logging using [tag:logcat], disable or change the network state, see for how long the system lags, and then stop logging. The log would be too much to scroll, but if an app is receiving the connectivity change broadcast or causing the lag, then it would show up in log.

Comment: I got the exact same problem, Galaxy S5 user here on Lollipop. I think this problem only happens on Samsung phones. I had the same problem with my S3. I did not have this problem with my HTC Desire Z, although that's a very old phone